# Global array does not have 'type' when added to header file in C code

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I am trying to use a global variable across multiple cpp files. To do so, I added the variable to a header file called `system.h` and created a variable inside of it:

```
extern int test_variable[];
```

Now in my `file1.cpp` I included the `system.h` header and initialized the variable with values:

```
int test_variable[10] = {0,2,4};
```

In `file2.cpp` I want to add a new number to the array and then print out the array. `system.h` is also included at the top of the file:

```
test_variable[4] = 7;

void saveToSD(){
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  Serial.print(test_variable[i]);
}
```

However, I receive an error stating that the `test_variable` in the `file2.cpp` does not name a type. What am I missing since I already initialized its type in the header file and `file1.cpp` states its type as well?

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: You can't have code outside of a function in C. Because it's outside of a function, C thinks it's a declaration and that "test_variable" must be a type.

Comment: Since you're programming for an Arduino you're programming C++. Don't tag both C and C++ (unless the question actually is about both languages) as it tends to upset people (and they really are two very different languages).

Comment: thanks everyone, I placed it into the function and now it works as described!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude noted. I am working/learning in Arduino environment so both program C/C++ work, thanks for the clarification. Won't do it again, and I'll change the tag. jk someone just did for me :)

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: More specifically,  you can't have *statements* outside a function. (The word "code" is more ambiguous.)

Comment: Terminology nit:  You didn't "add" or "create" a variable in the header file--you _declared_ it there.  A declaration tells the compiler that this variable will exist somewhere, but it doesn't actually create it.  In file1.cpp, you _defined_ it (and initialized it).  A definition will cause the compiler to actually "create" the variable.  These distinctions aren't always important, but sometimes they're critical.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy this is very helpful, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line `test_variable[4] = 7;` is an **assignment** (more generally, an executable line of code), not initialization, and is therefore not allowed outside of a function.

You need to either add this value as part of the initialization in file1, or move the assignment into a function.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I moved the assignment into the `saveToSD()` and works as you described. I appreciate the prompt help :) will accept when it allows me to